# Problems changing a class with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, class

So, I've been having problems getting my JavaScript to keep a element's class changed. Whenever I try and change the element's class to "overlist" it works for less than a second, and then reverts it right back to it's original state, underlist. I cannot figure out a way to make it so the class stays.

HTML:

```
<ul class="overlist">
    <li>
        <a onClick="activateTutorials()">Tutorials</a>
        <ul class="underlist Tutorials">
            <li>
                <a href="#" onClick="frame(1)">Filler Text</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" onClick="frame(2)">More Filler Text</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" onClick="frame(3)">Foo Tutorial</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" onClick="frame(4)">More foo Tutorial</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" onClick="frame(5)">Foo Guide</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

CSS:

```css
.underlist {
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```js
function activateTutorials(){

    if(document.getElementsByClassName('Tutorials').classList.contains('underlist')){

        document.getElementsByClassName('Tutorials').classList.remove('underlist');

    }else{

         document.getElementsByClassName('Tutorials').classList.add('underlist');

    }
};
```

Comment: Is that the right code? Nothing there would change `underlist` to `overlist` under any circumstances.

Comment: Sorry, hold up, I thought I copied the whole section. My bad.

Edit: I forgot the parenthesis on the end of the function, but if you could explain why it wouldn't change that would be much appreciated, I'm rather new to learning about changing classes.

Comment: None of the Javascript code ever adds "overlist" to anything. It's just adding or removing "underlist". By which I mean, literally, the word "overlist" does not occur in the code.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that, and realized I miss-typed my objective, thanks.

Comment: Just a suggestion: if you're just starting out, you may find it easier to begin with learning the jQuery library and then going back later to DOM manipulation in vanilla JS. With jQuery, that function could be written (assuming you give your `a` the id 'underlistToggle') `$("a#underlistToggle").click(function() { $(".Tutorials").toggleClass("underlist"); });` [Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/8Mu4J/1/). Just a suggestion and personal opinion--again, I know there are any number of reasons you might not want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some debugging thoughts:
Well, firstly you should have checked if the function was running or not(it wasn't for me)
I modified it like this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:activateTutorials();" class="Tutorials">Tutorials</a>
```

Secondly, getElementsByClassname returns an array so modify your script like this:

```
function activateTutorials(){
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('Tutorials'));
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('Tutorials')[0].classList.contains('underlist'))
 {
     document.getElementsByClassName('Tutorials')[0].classList.remove('underlist');
 }else{
     document.getElementsByClassName('Tutorials')[0].classList.add('underlist');
 }
};
```

You might have noticed a console statement in the begining of your function, it is a means of debugging(in chrome access it with Ctrl+Shift+J).